# Authorization for laravel passport through socket.io for broadcasting channels

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, laravel-5, socket.io

I'm using `laravel 5.3` + passport for authorization, `Laravel` is my back-end API which is `restful`.

front-end is written in `angular.js` which communicate with API with rest requests.

For Real-time notifications, I've used `laravel` broadcasting events + `redis`, and `socket.io` for socket server and socket client in `angular.js.`

I want to authorize these events and I've done it far as I could :

BroadcastServiceProvider :

```
public function boot()
{
   Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
   Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) 
   {
     return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
   });

   Broadcast::channel('notifs.*', function ($user, $userId) {
     return $user->id === (int) $userId;
   });
}
```

This is my socket.js code which runs my socket server :

```
var app   = require('express')();
var http  = require('http').Server(app);
var io    = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.psubscribe('*', function(err, count) {});

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
    console.log(channel);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});

redis.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The problem is I don't know how to authenticate these broadcasting events in socket server and also how to authorize the user in `angular.js (SPA)` to listen to these events.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Looked at socketio-auth? Last time I had to authenticate socket server side I just rolled my own token based (HMAC) thingy.

Comment: @ficuscr Can you take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187836/whats-the-security-risks-of-unauthorized-laravel-event-broadcasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely take a look at [socketio-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-auth).

> This module provides hooks to implement authentication in socket.io
>   without using querystrings to send credentials, which is not a good
>   security practice.

Another approach I took recently was simple token based authentication using [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) tokens ([njwt](https://github.com/jwtk/njwt)).

I did not want to recreate the authentication code that checks user credentials within Node.js. (which in my case can't even connect to the database anyway). Rather, I'd let the PHP application that was using the socket leverage its already established authentication system. Passing a signed token with the socket connect requests.

Your node.JS code might look something like...

```
primus.on('connection', function (spark) {

    logger.debug('primus event connection.  spark id: ' + spark.id);

    spark.on('data', function(data) {

        var action = data.action;

        njwt.verify(data.token, JWT_SECRET, function(err, verifiedJwt) {
            if (err) {
                logger.warn('Bad JWT Token! ' + spark.id + ' Error: ' + err);
                spark.user = {id:null, is_authed: false, is_admin: false, application_ini: null};
                spark.end('Bad Token Request');
                return; //->
            }

            spark.user = {  'id': verifiedJwt.body['user_id'],
                            'is_authed': verifiedJwt.body['is_authed'],
                            'application_ini': verifiedJwt.body['application_ini'],
                            'is_admin': verifiedJwt.body['is_admin']};

            sockoasRooms.connect(spark.id, spark.user.application_ini, spark.user.id); 


            switch (action) {
            ...
```

And then on the PHP side, you'll need some [code for generating the JWT tokens](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt), but use is very simple. Something like:

```
<?php
$tokenPayload = [   'user_id'           => ($this->currentUser) ? $this->currentUser->getId() : 0,
                    'is_authed'         => ($this->currentUser) ? true : false,
                    'application_ini'   => (string) APPLICATION_INI,
                    'is_admin'          => (bool) ($this->currentUser) ? $this->currentUser->isAdministrator() : false,
                    'now'               => time()
];
$jwtToken = \OAS_JWT::encode($tokenPayload, SOCK_OAS_JWT_KEY);

?>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    primus = Primus.connect('ws://<?=SOCK_OAS_IP?>:<?=SOCK_OAS_PORT?>/_admin');

    primus.on('open', function () {
        showConnected();
        // Send request to subscribe
        primus.write({action: 'dashboard-dump', token: '<?=$jwtToken?>'});
        consoleWrite('Connected to dashboard.');
    });
```

You can evaluate the time component to avoid replay attacks. Anyway, sounds like this approach might meet your needs.

Off topic but I'd also suggest taking a look at [primus](https://github.com/primus/primus). It acts as a "universal wrapper for real-time frameworks". This lets you abstract things in a way so you could swap out the socket libraries with no hassle. Might be a little lower level (engine.IO) than what you are using though.

Comment: As far as authorization, use what you already have in the application (laravel w/ passport), don't give token/ws URI if not authorized?

Comment: laravel does support private channels but i couldn't find anything about authorizing from socket server into laravel, today I made some changes which i authorize my angular app with passport post request then for the part I need real time notification I send the access token to socket server

Comment: which from socket server I will send a get request to one of user routes to check if it's authorized, if it is authorized then I give it permission to communicate to the client, if not I close and disconnect socket server